# Spring Boot Admin problem fetching the datas and menus

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

I'm trying to config the SpringBoot Admin with Eureka microservices..

After finish all the configs, i can see the SBA but a lot of resource was blocked and in service console i got this exception:

```
    java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software on the host computer
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1306) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:679) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:669) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:646) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.flush(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:169) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:252) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1561) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:380) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:514) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:514) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:43) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:226) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:200) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.send(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:190) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:189) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:133) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$SseEmitterSubscriber.send(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:366) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$AbstractEmitterSubscriber.run(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:309) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

My code:

SpringBootAdminApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
public class SpringBootAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String adminContextPath;

    public WebSecurityConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
        this.adminContextPath = adminServerProperties.getContextPath();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage(adminContextPath + "/login").successHandler(successHandler).and()
                .logout().logoutUrl(adminContextPath + "/logout").and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

POM.xml (First try):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.srmasset.springbootadmin</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootAdmin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootAdmin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.0.3</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>                        
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

Pom.xml (Second try):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.srmasset.springbootadmin</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootAdmin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootAdmin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.0.3</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 9999
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-boot-admin
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: password
  boot:
    admin:
      discovery:
        ignored-services: spring-boot-admin
eureka:
  enabled: true
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

With this configuration, i can acess the SBA, like the images bellow:

[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feGrt.png)

[Application page (looks normally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmrzI.png)

[Error in service health details and don't show the menu for graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mdOg.png)

[How it should looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85SPC.png)

Does anyone know why that happens or/and what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with spring boot admin. I could not visualize info of registered client in eureka.

I had to add this configuration in my application.yml of my microservices.

```
 management:
   endpoints:
     web:
       exposure:
         include: "*"
```

According to [documentation](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/):

> As with Spring Boot 2 most of the endpoints aren’t exposed via http by default, we expose all of them. For production you should carefully choose which endpoints to expose.

Are you including above configuraton in clients? Can you share you spring boot client  application.yml ?

You can check my sample [here](https://github.com/eberttc/spring-cloud-demo). the monitor-app is implementing Springboot Admin. I hope it helps you

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late.. that not work :c
i keep geting the log in the spring admin: "java.io.IOException:An established connection was aborted by the software on the host computer"